# Does an inheritance chain create a chain of constructor calls?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I've been struggling with the concept of constructors in the context of inheritance. This confusion has been compounded by the fact that big changes were introduced to this topic with C+11 (i.e. base constructors can be inherited?).

So my question:

Assuming I don't use constructor inheritance, but just define a new constructor in my derived class, does the base constructor still get called? It seems like it shouldn't, but I've come across some documents stating that this does occur. Furthermore, does that mean when you have an inheritance chain, there will be a series of constructors called? If so, in what order? Base before derived, or derived before base?

Thank you!

Comment: Unless you call `super()`, I believe the answer is _no_.

Comment: @EricM. The answer is still no with `super()`, because it won't compile

Comment: LOL! I knew it worked in java... I was 60%, maybe 70% sure it worked in c++. TIL.

Comment: The short answer is yes, the compiler will call parent constructor first, and call child constructor after that, but I don't have an extended explanation.

Comment: You can easily test it by `cout` something in the ctor.

Comment: @EricM. If you're thinking of Java, you're wrong, because `super()` is always called unless you're `java.lang.Object`, and if you're thinking of C++ you're even wronger, because there is no `super()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the order:

Here’s what actually happens when derived is instantiated:

> 1. Memory for derived is set aside (enough for both the Base and
>      Derived portions)
> 2. The appropriate Derived constructor is called
> 3. The Base object is constructed first using the appropriate Base constructor. If no base constructor is specified, the default
>      constructor will be used.
> 4. The initialization list initializes variables
> 5. The body of the constructor executes
> 6. Control is returned to the caller

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please explain step 2 and 3. In step 2 it says that the derived constructor is called, and then in step 3 it says 'the base object is constructed first using the appropriate base constructor'. What's called first?

Comment: As I know,  before the derived constructor can do anything substantial, the Base constructor is called first. The Base constructor sets up the Base portion of the object, control is returned to the Derived constructor, and the Derived constructor is allowed to finish up its job.

Comment: What's the difference between step 2 and step 5? What does it mean to call the constructor if it doesn't execute its body?

Comment: @Barma Calling it (2) starts its execution; it executes its base class constructor(s) (3), its initializers (4), and then its own body (5).